# Leading of National Assembly in case of absence

Tags: law, constitution, democracy, pakistan

Who will be the presiding officer of National Assembly when both speaker and deputy speaker are absent in the National Assembly of Pakistan??

Comment: Re-tagged from UK (why?) to Pakistan

Comment: Because Pakistan follow the constitution of UK

Comment: That would be rather remarkable, given that Pakistan is a Republic and the UK is not. (as is obvious from the K in UK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Constitution of Pakistan](http://www.pakistani.org/pakistan/constitution/part3.ch2.html), Article 53, clause 3

> When the office of Speaker is vacant, or the Speaker is absent or is unable to perform his functions due to any cause, the Deputy Speaker shall act as Speaker, and if, at that time, the Deputy Speaker is also absent or is unable to act as Speaker due to any cause, such member as may be determined by the rules of procedure of the Assembly shall preside at the meeting of the Assembly.

The same rules apply to the Senate, as

> The provisions of clauses (2) to (7) of Article 53 [...] shall apply to the Senate as they apply to the National Assembly and, in their application to the Senate, shall have effect as if references therein to the National Assembly, Speaker and Deputy Speaker were references, respectively, to the Senate, Chairman and Deputy Chairman